# Sign change in the modified Bessel differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

The modified Bessel differential equation is:

$$x^2y" + xy' - (x^2 + n^2)y = 0$$

I want to solve a differential equation and then calculate the Fourier transform of slightly different equation:
$$x^2y" + xy' - (cx^2 - n^2)y = 0$$

I  found that the solution to the above equations can be written in terms of solutions of the first equation in the following way:

$$K_{in} = \frac{\pi}{2 \sinh{\pi n}} [I_{-in}(x) - I_{in}(x)]$$

I wanted to calculate the Fourier transform of $K_{ia}$ but since the order of the Modified Bessel function is imaginary, I am not sure what to do. Can anyone point out any reference?

Comment: I think that you forgot in both equations the $y$ which multiplies the last term.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, thanks for that. Corrected.